# ImageResize on Android

Tags: android, image, image-resizing, resize-image

I am trying to work on a small requirement which provides users with an option to resize an image to a given percentage. Lets say 75% is the option. Does that mean I should **resize** the image size to 75% or the **resolution** of the image to 75%?

Any thoughts on this?

I wanted to use

> Bitmap yourBitmap;  resized =
>   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.75),
>   (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.75), true);

For the newWidth and newHeight should I blindly pass calculate like above?

Comment: Ask user what he/she wants

Comment: what you tried so far ??

Comment: I wanted to use    Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

Answer (score 0):

I think

image resolution is 100%  like 100x100 or 200x200 or 1000x1000

user want to resize it to 75%

I think scaleX, scaleY

so on the end image must be 75% like 75x75 or 150x150 or 750x750

Answer (score 0):

Within the help of Bitmap.createScaledBitmap you can resize your image even without losing your image quality

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, wantedWidth, wantedHeight, true);
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: I had a look into this api, but was wondering how would I calculate the wantedWidth and wantedHeight? Should I take the existing height and width and just calculate 75% of it and pass?

Comment: @Android_dev_new In that case you should take a proportion resolution for resizing image i.e 150*150 or 200*200 even if every image will become very large it should maintain this ratio

Answer (score 0):

You can implement as following way.

/*** sample code ***/

```
Bitmap srcBitmap;
Bitmap destBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBitmap, (int)(srcBitmap.getWidth()*0.75), (int)(srcBitmap.getHeight()*0.75), true);
```

Hopefully...

Answer (score 0):

What you consider to be 75% of an image is up to you. There are several posibilities. A nice variant is to resize to a predetermined size like 1024 for width if landscape and for height if portrait.

All the here suggested techniques can often not be used as they construct a full blown original bitmap first. Often memory for that will not be available.

So scale it down while loading. BitmapFactory will do it for you.